# How can I do this function pythonic?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python 2D function `f(x,y)` that returns a number for every pair `x` and `y`. I need to calculate `f(x,y)` having the elements in a list `x=[x0,x1,x2,x3], y=[y0,y1,y2,y3]` to obtain `[f(x0,y0),f(x1,y1),f(x2,y2),f(x3,y3)]`. I am doing this task with a for loop

```
result=[]
for k in range(len(k)):
    result.append(f(x[i],y[i]))
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?if possible with numpy arrays. Many thanks

Comment: Use zip and list comprehension, is generally consider more pythonic

Comment: I would use a comprehension: `result = [f(a, b) for a, b in zip(x, y)]`

Comment: Why is this tagged as `numpy`? The built-in `list`s and Numpy arrays have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @flakes this kind of thing is exactly what `map` is built for; it implicitly zips sequences of parameters. So all you need is `result = list(map(f, x, y))`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel huh... Today I learned! Didn't relaize it took more than two args. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy is a good idea.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])

def f(x, y):
    return x*y

z = f(x,y)
print(z) # array([ 0,  4, 12, 24])
```

Comment: Dependencies aren't free, don't use them if you can do without. I would only do this if I already had numpy in the dependencies, or if it was found to be computationally expensive without it. This would add about 10 to 15MB of bloat to your install size.

Comment: And several seconds to startup time, IMX.